choosing the non-empty group when I have multiple regex matches in a python regex?
I have a regex defined as such, it's two regular expressions separated by an OR - I want to find lines from a text file that match either of these regexes...
my_regex = re.compile(r'^\s+V.*CORE.*?: (\S+)|^\s+NP._VDDC_V: (\S+)')    
#                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                               regex1              regex2

# now we do the search... 
my_match = my_regex.search(line)

the lines I am searching will match regex1 or regex2 or neither (but never both!).  The value I'm interested in is the \S+ enclosed in grouping parenthesis in both regexes.
When the line matches regex1, I get what I want by looking at my_match.groups(1).  But when the line matches regex2, I have to go get what I want from my_match.groups(2).
Is there a super slick pythonic way to say "give me the group from the thing that actually matched" ?
I know that I can do something like dig through the match object, looking at my_match.regs... the group that didn't match will be .regs[n] = (-1,-1) so and the one that did match will have actual offsets ... I could look at them in order and find the one that is NOT (-1,-1)... but it seems like there's always some much more elegant way to do this that I'm just not aware of.

Can you give an example of one or two lines and what result you'd ideally expect for those? It's not entirely clear what you mean by "give me the group from the thing that actually matched". If you just want the result, and don't care to know why it matched, you could just get rid of the grouping with ?:. If you want to know which one matches, you could just trying matching the first and only try the second if the first doesn't work?

In this case, just put the capture group outside the alternation, so there's only one place to look: ^\s+(?:V.*CORE.*?: |NP._VDDC_V: )(\S+)

An easy way to get the actually matched part:
matched = my_match[1] or my_match[2]


Since you did not provide sample data, I used dummy data to ilustrate the point. Regex matches strings that start with a or b and captures everything after. Fails to match the string "yrhasr", and matches all else.

import re

strs=["abcde","bcsgsad","agdabn","aay","yrhasr","basdgt"]

pattern=re.compile(r"^a(.*)|^b(.*)")

for string in strs:
    r=pattern.search(string)
    if r:
        print(r.group(1) or r.group(2))
    else:
        print("i did not match")



Really consider the approach of @jasonharper - I think it is more elegeant!
